# Is there any way to get the (web-scrape) daily number that appears on this website? Need to scrape it for a years time

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Here is the website:
https://www.nbim.no/en/the-fund/market-value

Essentially I need to scrape the number under the header (Current market value). Right now it is: 10 917. The problem is that is only for today. I need to get that daily data number from the beginning of 2020. Is it possible?

Where might I find where that daily data is being stored?
Would like to do this in python.

Thank you

Comment: This you cannot do with requests and web scraping. You should probably dig through the source code and find out where they keep their records, if they even do. If you find that, then you could send a request and do all that.

Comment: If you want to find the current value starting from today, you could do that. Just ask a seperate question or edit this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you go into the `Network` tab of Inspect Element on your browser you should see where the server queries the information from. By the looks of it, it does so from the following API endpoint:

```
https://www.nbim.no/LiveNavHandler/Current.ashx?l=en-GB&t=1615058211098&PreviousNavValue=0&key=263c30dd-d5ba-41d6-a9b1-c1fb59cf30da
```

If you navigate there you would see JSON data representing what is shown the page. The `&t=` parameter seems to be epoch time, where (check [here](https://www.epochconverter.com/))

```
1615058211098 = Saturday, March 6, 2021 2:16:51.098 PM
```

However, even when changing that time to some historical value, the server still returns back todays query. On first look, unless the website has some historical endpoint, this doesn't look possible from the webpage you gave.

---

I should mention that the website *does* seem to provide historical figures via a table formatted in the HTML, as well as an excel downloadable. You should be able to extract this data using `requests` and `beautifulsoup`.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately the historical figures/excel show yearly averages not what the current market value is for each day of the 365 days. Not seeing where the JSON can be edited for historical data. I would imagine they save it somewhere, but not sure.

Comment: It doesn't seem like the historical data is available. I would recommend perhaps shooting them an email [here](https://www.norges-bank.no/en/topics/Statistics/open-data/), and reaching out for the data. Unsure if they would be willing to comply, but it's worth a shot. The other thing is scraping that data daily and storing it yourself- but that would render it useless until a set amount of time, I would assume.